# Want to have emails as a query string, but when the model binds them, it cuts off the string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I'm trying to make a GET request that has an email as a query string. For example:

```
api.com/product?email=email.com  


public async Task<IActionResult> GetEvents(string email)
```

When it tries to bind the email to the query string, sometimes it leaves off a couple of characters from the end, for instance, sometimes it will be `email.` or `email.c`. Does it have to do with the dot?

Comment: does happen by using a real email address (i.e. including the @ symbol) or even with the text used in the example?

Comment: @jon-sherman you can encode and try it

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example... we need to know how you are "issuing" these requests and what the debug values look like.  We need to be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Whether the url is dynamic generate or not? After getting the email in the action method, please check your code, whether you want to extract part of the string? It is better to post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).